# Concurrent Connections Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Hello is there a way to see concurrent connections on my server.

Server info:
ubuntu server 11.10
apache2

99% of the site connects to mysql and it tells me the concurrent connections of MySQL can I go by that?

The reason I'm asking I'm thinking about switching from dedicated hosting back to cloud hosting with a load balancer. They charge per 100 concurrent connections.

Thank you.

I tried the mod status and got

```
   Server uptime: 3 minutes 11 seconds
   Total accesses: 41097 - Total Traffic: 24.0 MB
   CPU Usage: u331.39 s16.82 cu0 cs0 - 182% CPU load
   215 requests/sec - 128.5 kB/second - 611 B/request
   334 requests currently being processed, 248 idle workers
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache's `mod_status` can give you this information.

And no, don't go by the connections to MySQL; most applications utilize some kind of connection pooling which abstracts the connection from the request.

Comment: I got  `   Server uptime: 3 minutes 11 seconds
   Total accesses: 41097 - Total Traffic: 24.0 MB
   CPU Usage: u331.39 s16.82 cu0 cs0 - 182% CPU load
   215 requests/sec - 128.5 kB/second - 611 B/request
   334 requests currently being processed, 248 idle workers`

Comment: `334 requests currently being processed` is your answer.  You'll probably want to keep an eye on peak hours to get a good idea of the number that you'll need to provision for.

Comment: That means that at the moment you have 334 open connections.

Comment: Thank you didn't know I had that many at once ehh will be costly.